# React Router 6 - Page Refresh Resets To Base Path '/'

Tags: react-router

Hello and thanks in advance for any feedback.
I am building out an app with React Router 6 with several nested routes.
The issue that I keep running into is that on-page refresh the router navigates back to the base route...
meaning if I am on `/about` and hit refresh - the App is going to navigate back to the `'/'` URL.

It may be worth adding that if I click on  `<- back` or `forward ->` browser buttons the app behaves as expected and navigates to the previous URL.

This is obviously less than ideal.

Comment: Ever find a solution for this?  Same issue here with react-router 6

Answer (score -1):

I know the question is a bit old but to avoid the navigation to `/` on refresh, you could use `<Link>` which `react-router-dom` provides.

#### App.jsx

```jsx
<nav>
   <Link to="/">Home</Link>
   <Link to="/about">About</Link>
</nav>

<Routes>
   <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
   <Route path="/about" element={<About/>} />
</Routes>
```